# How to handle ad hoc composites of glossary entries with a prefix, using the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries

Imagine I have an acronym entry `\newacronym{rmse}{RMSE}{root-mean-square error}` and I specifically want to refer to the *test set RMSE*, explaining eg. the concept of cross-validation. Imagine furthermore that I cannot (or do not want to) assert the status of the first use flag of that entry at some particular point in the document.

Things like `test set \gls{rmse}` will not work properly on first use, because it will produce something like "test set root-mean-square error (RMSE)", but I would rather have it display "test set root-mean-square error (test set RMSE)", to avoid confusion about what exactly "RMSE" stands for.

I could use a construction like `\gls{rmse} on the test set`, but find it very inelegant, especially in the non-first-use case.

Below is a MWE showing my current workaround using a combination of `ifglsused` and some other `glossaries` commands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{rmse}{RMSE}{root-mean-square error}

\newcommand*{\mygls}[2]{%
    \ifglsused{#2}{%
        % short
        #1 \gls{#2}%
    }{%
        % long
        #1 \glsentrylong{#2} (#1 \glsentryshort{#2})\glsunset{#2}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    Step 4: Compute the \mygls{test set}{rmse}.

    Step 4: Compute the \mygls{test set}{rmse}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above LaTeX code block]

As can be seen, this works quite well, but is very inflexible (I might want to `\myGls` or `\myglspl`, for example).

Is there a better way to do this? Preferably, a `glossaries` or `glossaries-extra` command that I somehow happened to oversee?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx